# c program to swap values printing wrong result

Tags: c, function, integer, parameter-passing

Hi I have written a c program that reads in 2 values then swaps them and prints the new values except the second value keeps showing 0. For example it you enter 10 for 'a' and 8 tor 'b',  then a will be 8 but b will be 0. Does anyone know the solution to fix this? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getData()
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    return(a, b);
}

void swapValues(int a, int b)
{

    printf("The value of a is: %d", b);
    printf("\nThe value of b is: %d", a);

    return;
}

int main()
{

    int a, b = getData();
    swapValues(a, b);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: -1 Have you tried to use the debugger before asking?

Comment: It compiled that's why it confused me

Comment: If it compiles that does not mean that it works correctly. Technically, there is no compilation errors in your code. But from the functionality point of view, it doesn't work at all.
Using of debugger allow to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unnecessarily complicated the whole thing.For one, something like return(a,b) is absurd in C.Further, if you intend to swap, why are  you passing b as argument for the printf() meant to print 'a' and passing a to the printf() of 'b'?Anyways,here's a modified code that keeps it simple and gets the job done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapValues()
{
    int a, b,tem;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("\nEnter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    tem=a;
    a=b;
    b=tem;

    printf("\nThe value of a is: %d", a);
    printf("\nThe value of b is: %d", b);

        }



int main()
{

    swapValues();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's obvious the poster is new to C, and perhaps programming in general. Perhaps explain *why* `return(a,b)` is absurd in C.

Comment: Thanks it actually made me laugh how unnecessarily complicated it was once I looked at yours

Comment: @user2147550 The ability to laugh at one's own mistakes is one of the biggest assets a person can have!!

Answer (score 2):

```
return (a, b);
```

doesn't do what you think it does, it's a misapplication of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

The expression `op1, op2` evaluates both `op1` and `op2` but gives you the value of `op2`. So it's not passing back a couple of values (although some languages like Python can do this sort of thing).

Similarly,

```
int a, b = getData();
```

won't grab the mythical two values returned from `getData()`. Rather it will set `a` to an indeterminate value and set `b` based on the single value returned from the function.

I would be looking at something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getData (char *which) {
    int val;

    printf ("Enter value for %s: ", which);
    scanf("%d", &val);

    return val;
}

void swapValues (int a, int b) {
    printf("The swapped value of a is: %d\n", b);
    printf("The swapped value of b is: %d\n", a);
}

int main (void) {
    int a = getData ("a");
    int b = getData ("b");
    swapValues(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

You should also keep in mind that, if you *actually* want to swap the variables `a` and `b` and have that reflected back to `main`(rather than just print them as if they've been swapped), you'll need to pass pointers to them and manipulate them via the pointers.

C is a pass-by-value language meaning that changes to function parameters aren't normally reflected back to the caller. That would go something like this:

```
void swapValues (int *pa, int *pb) {
    int tmp = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = tmp;
}
:
swapValues (&a, &b);
// a and b are now swapped.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return multiple values from a C function. I'm not even sure why the statement `return(a, b)` compiles.

If you want to return more than value from a function you should either put them into an array or a structure. I'm going to use a structure to demonstrate one way to do this correctly. There are many ways to do this, but this one modifies you code the least.

```
struct TwoNums{
    int a;
    int b;
};

TwoNums getData()
{
    /* This creates a new struct of type struct TwoNums */
    struct TwoNums nums;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nums.a));

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nums.b));

    return(a, b);
}

void swapValues(int a, int b)
{

    printf("The value of a is: %d", b);
    printf("\nThe value of b is: %d", a);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    /* Get the whole structure in one call */
    struct TwoNums nums = getData();

    /* Call the swap function using fields of the structure */
    swapValues(nums.a, nums.b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned arrays or structures yet, could I just use pointers to solve this?

Comment: -1, your code lists 10 errors/warnings. `return(a, b);` this is wrong.

Comment: @Armin This was not supposed to be the entire thing. I only implemented functions that need to be replaced.

Comment: @Armin Now it should build.

Comment: Still won't build, but you did get rid of one error, note this is `c` we are talking about did you compile with c++?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't return more than one value in C. The way around that is to return a struct or pass the values address.

```
void getData(int *a,int* b)
{
   //int a, b;

   printf("Enter first number: ");
   scanf("%d", a); // look here you passed the address of a to scanf
                    // by doing that scanf can write to a 

   printf("Enter second number: ");
   scanf("%d", b);

   //return(a, b);
  }
```

The old main:

```
  int main()
  {

    int a, b = getData(); // b gets the return value from getData()
                          // but a is still uninitialized
    //to call the new function you have to do the following
    int a,b;
    getData(&a,&b);
    swapValues(a, b);

    return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

without using temporary variable.
So try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int swape()
   {
  int a,b;
  printf("Enter first number: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);


printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%d", &b);
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;


printf("The value of a is: %d", a);
printf("\nThe value of b is: %d", b);

}

int main()
{

swape();

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first:

`getData()` function is written incorrectly.
   You **can not** return **more than one** parameter from the function in C. So you can to separate data reading, or use pointers as below:

```
void getData(int* a, int* b) {

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", a);

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", b);
}
```

In `main()`

```
int a, b;
getData(&a, &b);
```

The second:

`swapValues(int a, int b)` **does not swap the data**.

More correct:

```
void swapValues(int* a, int* b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```